# Django Rest Framework: After adding related field with serializer I get Integrity error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I had the following serializer. Django Rest Framework allows me to create, update, delete and get info just with this code. Of course I'm adding the serializer to the viewset but the problem is not there:

```
class MeasurmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Measurment
        fields = ('id', 'user_statistic', 'value', 'date_created')
```

I needed to add the detailed info for the field "user_statistic" whenever I GET the data, not just the URL so I added the code in second line and it worked, I got the extra info I needed:

```
class MeasurmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user_statistic = UserStatisticSerializer(read_only=True) # New Code Added

    class Meta:
        model = Measurment
        fields = ('id', 'user_statistic', 'value', 'date_created')
```

However the when I POST to the API to create new info into the database it shows the following error:

> NotNullViolation: null value in column "statistic_id" of relation
> "cms_userstatistic" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:
> Failing row contains (55, 6, 0, f, f, null, 2022-01-05, 2022-01-05,
> null, 67).

It seems that serializing a related field prevents DRF to get the related field info whenever it tries to create a new object. How can I add the detailed info for that specific related field without breaking the POST request? I wonder if there is another way of getting this info without using the function "to_representation" that allows me to customize the resulting object.

I thank you all for any clue you can give me.

Comment: is statistic_id a field in model? if possible you can add null=true to avoid the error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You show the serializer here, but don't give us the model definitiion that it goes with. You also need to show an example `POST` request, especially the data that you are posting. Also, how do you expect the `user_statistic` field get set when you create a new `Measurement` object? Is `user_statistic` required? Or should it be allowed to be `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just serialize your `user_statistic` into the other field:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

# ...

class MeasurmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user_statistic_detailed = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Measurment
        fields = ('id', 'user_statistic', 'value', 'date_created', 
                  'user_statistic_detailed')

        def get_user_statistic_detailed(self, record):
            return serialize(UserStatisticSerializer, record.user_statistic)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could do that. This worked perfect!

Comment: @AndrésRoot glad to help :)